# How to make auto generated data contract class in client side implement an interface?

Tags: c#, wcf

I need the data contract class on the client side to implement certain interface. This interface is guaranteed to contain exactly the same properties as the data contract itself, so there will be no compilation errors.

The data contract class on the server side is **not** available on an assembly shared by the server and the client. All the properties on this class are computed and it has too many dependencies that makes it  impractical to make it available on an assembly shared with the client.

What do I need to do to make the (autogenerated?) data contract class on the client side implement an interface? I own both the server and the client side.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the autogeneration tool svcutil? Do you own both the server and the client code or is the client side developed by another party?

Comment: @henginy yes, I own both client and server (will update question to clarify). Regarding the autogeneration tool, I am currently using the Add Service Reference feature in VS.

Comment: I believe Add Service Reference uses svcutil behind the scenes.  In any case, I would expect the generated Data Contract to effectively implement `IFoo`, as the autogeneration would be based on the `Foo` implementation in your service.

Comment: @Tim, the `Foo` class on the client side (auto generated by the Add Service Reference feature) does not implement the shared `IFoo` interface. It has the same properties as the interface, but it is not a subclass.

Comment: @beluchin - Yes, I understand that - which is why I said "effectively implements IFoo`.  Are you trying to make the client implement `IFoo` in the same manner that the service does?  That doesn't make sense to me - it would seem to break SOA.  Can you clarify why you want the client to implement a specific interface rather than consume the DataContract generated by the service?

Comment: @Tim, yes, I want to make the client implement IFoo in the same manner as the Foo class in the server. The client needs to pass that object to another library that accepts IFoo objects.

Comment: @beluchin - Ah, now I get it.  From an autogenerated point of view I don't believe that is possible - reason being that the Server's `Foo` class implementing `IFoo` is an implementation detail, and the client doesn't need to know about that.  Since you have control over both the server and the client, you might be able to force this by manually creating your proxy.  Another alternative might be to put the Data Contract that implements `IFoo` in the same shared assembly or another shared assembly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32913/discussion-between-beluchin-and-tim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes on the client side are generated as partials. If you create another partial class with the same name, you can apply the appropriate interface to that partial.